# Using MYSQL, How do I query a table only if it exists already?

Tags: mysql

Im writing a migration and Im trying to query a table only if it exists in the db. In some envs it will exist and in others it wont which is why i want to check if it exists. The table of interest is called OLD_PASSWORD. I do the following.

```
SELECT ID, PASSWORD
      FROM OLD_PASSWORD;
      WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'OLD_PASSWORD);
```

This fails '.dbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "USER_OLD_PASSWORDS" not found;' which makes sense because it wont exist in some envs.

I also tried something like

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT *
             FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
             WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'OLD_PASSWORD'))
  BEGIN
      SELECT ID,
             PASSWORD
      FROM   OLD_PASSWORD
  END
```

but it's not compatible with mysql.

Comment: You can only use `IF` statements in a stored procedure, not SQL queries.

Comment: It's not possible to write a SQL query that does what you want.

Comment: Any ideas on what other ways I can approach this?

Comment: Use a stored procedure or do it from a programming language like PHP or Python.

Comment: What language are you writing the migration script in?

Comment: Java. Im using JdbcTemplate/

Comment: So you should be able to query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` from Java, and then do the query from `OLD_PASSWORD` if it returns something.

Comment: Or just do the query and catch and ignore the `dbcSQLSyntaxErrorException`

Comment: @Barmar your approach was the right way to go. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Best approach was to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES from Java, and then do the query from OLD_PASSWORD if it returns something.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `'` sign at the end of query before the `)`.

Nonetheless, this is cartesian select. Use in instead. i.e

```
password in (select password  ...) etc.
```